# Multiple VPN Connections over single IP (multithreaded)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ip, vpn

Is there a way to make each thread in C# to connect to single VPN?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

VPNs are not thread based or really even process based.  They're low level drivers that emulate network connections.

Theoretically you can initiate multiple VPNs at once but they must all be configured to allow local network and each will route the appropriate addresses.  In practice, most VPN profiles prohibit local network access (and thus other VPN access) due to security ramifications.  Also, most VPN software conflicts with other VPN software.